# How to write function in array

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am new in programming in c. My question is how to write a function that will turn over my array. EX: input: 1,2,3,4,5 output:5,4,3,2,1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP outsourced the homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite way of doing this is to use pointers. The procedure works in such a way, that (for an array with known length) you have two pointers, pointing to either end of the array and a temporary storage value. Both pointers now start to move, one field after another, closer to the middle of the array, swapping their values with eachother in each step (this is what the temporaty value is needed for).

```
void swap_array(int *array, int length)
{
    int temp;
    // If the array has length 1, there is nothing to swap.
    if(length > 1){
        int *swp_1 = array; // swp_1 points to the start of the array.
        int *swp_2 = array + (length - 1); // swp_2 points to the end of the array.
        // Iterate over the array, swapping the value swp_1 points to,
        // with the value swp_2 points to, before moving swp_1 one further
        // up the array, and swp_2 one down, until the "middle"-Element is reached.
        for(int i = 0; i < (length / 2); i++){
            temp = *swp_1;
            *swp_1 = *swp_2;
            *swp_2 = temp;
            swp_1++; // Point to the next element.
            swp_2--; // Point to the previous element.
        }
    }
}
```

---

For feature reference: Please try to show an effort yourself before you ask questions like this one..

Comment: Could the downvoter maybe explain the reasoning behind it? I would love to improve the quality upon constructive feedback.